# Transform translation not getting picked up from css

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions, translation

So I'm trying to add transitions onto a slideout component, but the translation portion isn't getting picked up for some reason. The duration is clearly happening, but the translation is not.

```css
.enterLeave {
  --tw-translate-x: 0px;
  transform: translateX(--tw-translate-x) translateY(0) rotate(0) skewX(0)
    skewY(0) scaleX(1) scaleY(1);
  transition-property: background-color, border-color, color, fill, stroke,
    opacity, box-shadow, transform;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transition-duration: 500ms;
}

.translateX0 {
  --tw-translate-x: 0px;
}

.translateXFull {
  --tw-translate-x: 100%;
}
```

```
function Slideover({ children, isOpen, setIsOpen }) {
  return (
    <Transition
      show={isOpen}
      enter={"enterLeave"}
      enterFrom={"translateXFull"}
      enterTo={"translateX0"}
      leave={"enterLeave"}
      leaveFrom={"translateX0"}
      leaveTo={"translateXFull"}
    >
      <div className={`${"slideoverWrapper"}`}>
        <div className={"hfullFlexCol1"}>{children}</div>
      </div>
    </Transition>
  );
}
```

I can get it working fine for [opacity](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-sun-tfm3g?file=/src/Slideover/Slideover.jsx), but when I try to do the transition [it breaks down](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-napier-1epbl?file=/src/Slideover/Slideover.css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a CSS Custom Property (variable) but you are not referencing it properly

```
 translateX(--tw-translate-x)
```

should be

```
translateX(var(--tw-translate-x))
```

Comment: that did it! getting a weird Y axis shift now, but I should be able to figure it out. cheers